# Get comma separated list from Listbox with brackets around entire list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using vb.net and have a listbox that has items in it. I need to get a string list of the contents each preceded by "+1" and separated by a "," and also want the entire list enclosed in Curley brackets "{}",
Such as my listbox info:

- 12345678910
- 01987654321

I want the result to be

> "{+112345678910, +101987654321}"

NOT

> "+112345678910, +101987654321"

```
Dim MultiNums As String = ""
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

For Each Item In lbEmail1.Items
  sb.Append("+1" + Item.Text + ", ")
Next

MultiNums = sb.ToString()
```

The current output isn't adding the {}

Comment: Not sure why the question.  If you need { and } in your string, just append them  `MultiNums = "{" & sb.ToString() & "}"`.  Is there something more to this question?

Comment: Nothing more, pretty simple question. thank you I'm going to try that. I'm just rusty at this :)

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler, though yes, simply add the braces to the answer:

```
Dim MultiNums As String = String.Format("{{+1{0}}}", 
    String.Join("+1, ", lbEmail1.Items.Select(Function (n)(n.Text))))
```